# Android Update TextView via Handler on separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, android-edittext, handler

I am currently working on my first Android App for Uni. I am slowly getting there but I am stuck on a certain section.

The coursework requires a separate thread to that of the UIthread. My idea is the user can set their names in Name_edit.java then when they go to board.java (a different activity) the two textviews are now displaying what was entered

In the Name_edit.xml I have two edittexts.

In the board.java I have two textviews (currently set to P1 and P2 respectively). In the OnCreate() I am currently working on a handler to get the two values from (name_edit) the two edittexts and set this to the textviews. I believe this will require two handlers (one for each value). In the board.java I have done the standard findViewById.

Any help on Handlers and Threads would be helpful.

I would post my handler code but it is current changing constantly. What I am working on is

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        TextViewP1.setText(msg)
    }
};
```

Note msg is currently not set to an edittext from name_edit

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `runOnUiThread()`? UI elements can only be changed from the UI thread and your handler here runs on it's own thread.

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               TextViewP1.setText(msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

where `context` can be replaced with `[class name].this` if your handler is in your Activity class.

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: I have added what you have stated. For the context. I have replaced it with Board.this. This activity is where the TextViews are (Where the names from the editText will appear). I do get an error at TextViewP1.setText(msg); "Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable msg inside an inner class defined in a different method
 - The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments " Should there be some code present in NameEdit.java (This is the activity where the user would would enter the names in the editTexts) @shanet

Comment: @Dan1676 Have you tried making `TextViewP1` `final`? Or you can make it global.

Comment: just tried that in Board.java, gives errors. Should there be any code in name_edit where the user would edit/add the names?

Comment: @Dan1676 Lets look at this from a bigger perspective. Just so I'm not confused, tell me if this is right, `Name_edit.java` is an activity that the user enters names in. When the user is done entering names,  `Board.java` is another activity that displays the names, correct? If so, does the `Board` activity start the `Name_edit` activity? If so, I think you would be better off using `startActivityForResult()` and sending the names back in an array or bundle to the Board activity instead of using handlers. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. Name_edit.java and Board.java and indirectly linked via a main menu. I was about to use intents but I don't think data can be passed when the activities are not directly linked

Comment: @Dan1676 I'm not sure what you mean by directly vs indirectly linked, but you can pass custom data via Intents with `intent.putExtra()`. Otherwise, depending on where you're calling `startActivity()` from to start the `Name_edit` activity, you could change that call to `startActivityForResult()` and then override `onActivityResult()` in your `Board` activity to set the player names that were set as the result in the `Name_edit_ activity with `setResult()`. Look up those functions in the Android docs for more info.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help today. Will try what you said tomorrow been coding for 9 hours now so that's it for me. Again thanks for your help